# Search for a string inside an XML record and return the whole record to output file

Tags: xml, sed, grep, find

I have a bunch of XML files (file1, file2....file30) and each file has several records in it. Each record begins with <-Place> tag and ends with <-/Place> tag. Let's say I want to find any record which contains the element  1122  and return the whole record in this format:  <-Place> everything between the open & close tag <-/PLace>. How can I do that? Here is the sample input and expected output

Input:

File 1:

```
 <Place> <category> 1122 </category> </Place> <Place> <category> 1125 </category </Place> <Place> <category> 1122 </category </Place>
```

File 2:

```
<Place><category> 1122 </category> </Place> <Place><category> 1126 </category> </Place>
```

Out put:

`<Place> <category> 1122 </category> </Place> <Place> <category> 1122 </category </Place> <Place> <category> 1122 </category </Place>`

thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Post some actual sample input and expected output instead of just telling us a couple of things about it.

Answer (score 0):

You MAY want something like this:

```
awk '
/<-Place>/ { f=1 }
f { rec = rec $0 RS }
/<-\/Place>/ {
    if (rec ~ /1122/) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
    f = 0
}
'
```

but without sample input and expected output it's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks. I just removed the comment and updated the question instead